# drawing geo coordinates on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am busy with drawing geo coordinates on a canvas. What I do now is get coordinates transform them to Points en put them inside a polygon. When I add the polygon to my canvas, it just draws one small dot on the screen. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

the code that I have now is:

```
`var data = DH.Data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
            for (int x = 0; x < data.Length; x++)
            {
                var Data = DH.Data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[x];
                for (int y = 0; y < Data.Length; y++)
                {
                    Polygon p = new Polygon();
                    p.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    p.Fill = Brushes.Black;
                    p.StrokeThickness = 1;
                    var point0 = Data[0];
                    for (int z = 0; z < point0.Length; z++)
                    {
                        var point1 = point0[z];
                        Point n = new Point(point1[0], point1[1]);
                        p.Points.Add(n);
                    }
                    Canvas.Children.Add(p);
                }
            }`
```

Comment: I would check the looping, step through and see if it only does like 2 points rather than 20. Then look at the data it gets. Is it what you're expecting?

Comment: It also might be a scaling issue. If it draws 20 points all very close to each other you will see a dot.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem I am having right now. What is the best way to solve this?